# A sinon.spy function that is called does not state it has been called

Tags: javascript, ember.js, sinon

I'm trying to mock an EmberJS adapter which has a function that carries out a POST request. My test looks like this:

```
 test('should post something', async function (assert) {
    let controller = this.owner.lookup('path/to/ach-deposit');
  
    controller.setProperties({
      ...,
      store: {
        adapterFor: () => {
          return {postAchDeposit: sinon.spy()}
        }
      }
    })
    await controller.actions.postAchDepositHandler.call(controller);
    assert.ok(controller.store.adapterFor.call().postAchDeposit.called);

  })
```

This fails. Stepping into the code of where postAchDeposit is called throws no errors. If I were to change `sinon.spy()` to `sinon.stub().return("Hi")` it would return `Hi` but for whatever reason when I try to see if it has been called, it returns false.

In the debugger after postAchDeposit has been called if I check there using `this.get('store').adapterFor('funding/ach-deposit').postAchDeposit.called` still it returns false.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each time `adapterFor` is called `sinon.spy()` is called again and so a new spy is created.

So essentialls:

```
controller.store.adapterFor().postAchDeposit !== controller.store.adapterFor().postAchDeposit
```

You probably should first create your stub and then always pass a reference:

```js
    const postAchDeposit = sinon.spy();
    controller.setProperties({
      ...,
      store: {
        adapterFor: () => {
          return {postAchDeposit}
        }
      }
    });

    await controller.actions.postAchDepositHandler.call(controller);
    assert.ok(postAchDeposit.called);
```